# React : Improve URL structure for SEO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo

I'm making a react application and to fetch pages with data I'm actually using a generated token in the URL like this `http://localhost.com/a/xQ9aK2`  with  `xQ9aK2` as the token.

Having no previous experience regarding SEO, and while the application might have a lot of pages, I was wondering if I should restructure my URL to include something like a slug, or should I just keep the actual URL and maybe use `React-Router-Link` with `Redirect` to append a slug at the end of a URL after fetching data?

OR is there anything I can do in order to improve the ranking of the pages?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Keyword in URLs vs. short URLs](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132671/) and [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm sorry I didn't know about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to add an easy to read slug both for Googlebot as well as users. If you need the token in there for an identifier, that's absolutely ok to include as well:

```
http://localhost.com/a/top-nfts-to-watch-2022-xQ9aK2
```

Additionally, make sure you have a unique title tag for each page as well as H1s.

Comment: This is what I was thinkig. Thank you for the clarification.